# How to make quick judgement and assignment without isset()?

Tags: php, ternary-operator, isset

I am tired of using code like:

```
$blog = isset($_GET['blog']) ? $_GET['blog'] : 'default';
```

but I can't use:

```
$blog = $_GET['blog'] || 'default';
```

Is there any way to do this without using `isset()`?

Comment: Psst - you didn't hear it from me, but if you're going to assign `null` and you don't mind breaking a best-practice, you can suppress the notice and use `$blog = @$_GET['blog'];`  _[recedes back into shadow...]_

Comment: ^^^ In practice I would never do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wait for the next version of PHP to get the [coalesce operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary)

```
// Uses $_GET['user'] if it exists -- or 'nobody' if it doesn't
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';

// Loads some data from the model and falls back on a default value
$model = Model::get($id) ?? $default_model;
```

Comment: Man, the upcoming null coalesce operator is the most exciting feature PHP's gotten in years.

Comment: I can make this code even shorter `$u=$_GET['u'] ?? 'n'; $m=Model::get($id) ?? $d_m;` lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- All you need to do now is make it binary ;)

Comment: I'll let the OP do that lol - Hey.. [**seen this?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26489096/) what are the chances? ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Wow. What are the odds indeed? Glad you saw that or we'd be having this discussion all over again.

Comment: You know me eh? Code is like a fingerprint lol The guy didn't contest my comment, so I won't be calling it a "coincidence" anytime soon ;)

Answer (score 1):

Write a helper function.

```
function arrayValue($array, $key, $default = null)
{
    return isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}
```

Usage:

```
$blog = arrayValue($_GET, 'blog');
```

Answer (score 0):

No there is no shorter way than that. You can create a class that handles the $_POST and $_GET variables and just user it whenever you call the blog.

Example:

$blog = Input::put("blog");

The input class will have a static method which will determine when input is either have a $_POST and $_GET or a null value.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write a custom helper:

```
function get($name, $default=null){
    return isset($_GET[$name]) ? $_GET[$name] : $default;
}

$blog = get('blog', 'default');
```

Alternatively, you have the [filter extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php), e.g.:

```
$blog = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'blog') ?: 'default';
```

It's not noticeably shorter but allows further validation and sanitisation (and it's also trivial to wrap in a custom function).