# Short way for isset($a) ? $a : 'other';

Tags: php, short

is there any shorter way for this in PHP?

```
$b = isset($a) ? $a : 'other';
```

Like in JS

```
$b = $a || 'other';
```

This does not realy look like a big thing, but when you have a large list of properties/keys to check, this becomes annoing.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `$b = @$a ?: 'other';`

Comment: doing this does however murder all readability of the code :(

Comment: I would normally have one array, which I merge with an array with default values, which (1) has the advantage of just 1 point where the defaults are defined, and (2) is only 1 statement to merge. (Something like `$defaults = array("a"=> "123","b" => 456); $input = array("b"=>"custom"); var_dump(array_merge($defaults,$input));`)

Comment: @Dave not only that, it is a bad coding practice to use the error suppressor.

Comment: Why does this question look an awful lot like http://stackoverflow.com/q/26477475/ are you also tired of doing it that way, or are you the same guy? Ah, you find it "annoying", so I'd say you're of the same.

Comment: @Cthulhu: -1 for using the `@` operator.

Comment: @AzizSaleh you know i didn't even notice the @ in there oO

Comment: @MarcB too bad you cannot downvote the comments then :P And yes, the suppressor is really appropriate there imho to better reflect `isset` behavior.

Comment: @Cthulhu: +1 for using the @ operator well. I've seen it used in so many bad ways, but this is one of the few examples where it SHOULD be used.

Comment: @Cthulhu That's what i've been looking for. 
If i'm handling arrays array_merge($arrDefaults, $arrInput) is a good thing but i'm not sure about the performance if you are juggeling with stdClass like (object)array_merge($arrDefaults, (array)$objInput)

Answer (score 0):

A shorter ternary syntax has has been introduced in PHP 5.3. From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the
>   ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1
>   evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

What you want is however still not (properly) possible with this shorter syntax but requires the [coalesce operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary) to-be introduced in PHP 7.

Comment: Except that he wants `$a` into `$b`, not `isset($a)` (boolean).

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible if $a is guaranteed to exist. So in your case it would not be possible, because you seem to not know if $a is set.

```
$b = isset($a) ? $a : 'other';
```

But it would be in this case:

```
public function foo($var)
{
    $var = $var ?: self::DEFAULT;
}
```